# Sum a List of Dataframes by Column Number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of 5 dataframes each with 9 columns and 15000 rows. I am hoping to sum the columns from each dataframe to obtain a final 9*15000 dataframe.

I tried something like

```
Total = reduce(lambda x, y: x.add(y, fill_value=0), List)
```

All this does is append all columns to the df Total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If column names are the same for all dataframes, you can just add the dataframes:

```
result=df1+df2+df3+df4+df5
```

Column names must be the same for all dataframes. In order to rename them try this:

```
df2.columns=df1.columns
df3.columns=df1.columns
df4.columns=df1.columns
df5.columns=df1.columns
```

All dataframes will have same column names as df1, and the same with the result dataframe

Comment: When I do that it gives me a 45 column df.

[15118 rows x 45 columns]

The problem comes in because I have to index each individual element in the list. I guess I could split the list. Was just looking for a quicker way.

Comment: Are column names the same for all dataframes?

Comment: Column names are not the same. Sorry forgot to clarify that

Comment: If column names are the same they will be added up in the same column. It depends on your problem if you can rename all columns and do the sum

Comment: Yes I suppose I could rename the columns in each to the same. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can Directly add multiple dataframes as

```
Total=df1+df2+df3+df4+df5
```

but only if Dimensions of dataframes are same.